# spark processor dockerfile fails to build docker image- especially during installing sbt rpm packager

Tags: docker, apache-spark

```
=> ERROR [build 15/20] RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug unstable-debug main deb http:/  2.6s
------
 > [build 15/20] RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug unstable-debug main deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports unstable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list &&     if [ -d /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ]; then         rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*;     fi &&     gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C874011F0AB405110D02105534365D9472D7468F &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install sbt rpm -y &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
0.440 gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
0.441 gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
1.915 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
------
Dockerfile:26
--------------------
  25 |     RUN scala -nocompdaemon test.scala && rm test.scala
  26 | >>> RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug unstable-debug main deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports unstable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  27 | >>>     if [ -d /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ]; then \
  28 | >>>         rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; \
  29 | >>>     fi && \
  30 | >>>     # gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138 0E98404D386FA1D9 DCC9EFBF77E1157
  31 | >>>     gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C874011F0AB405110D02105534365D9472D7468F && \
  32 | >>>     apt-get update && \
  33 | >>>     apt-get install sbt rpm -y && \
  34 | >>>     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  35 |     USER root
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c echo \"deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug unstable-debug main deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports unstable main\" > /etc/apt/sources.list &&     if [ -d /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ]; then         rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*;     fi &&     gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C874011F0AB405110D02105534365D9472D7468F &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install sbt rpm -y &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

I have been trying to build the Spark processor dockerimage which could be useful for my project. I get this when the Dockerfile is trying to install sbt rpm native packager